# How do I adjust this background that wouldn't mess the mobile version?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a video background which is supposed to look like this:

[Video BG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHX5N.png)

But what I have right now is like this:

[Current Video BG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPwwT.png)

Now here's the whole code:

```html
<section class="header6 cid-qshCJQFC7b" data-bg-video="" id="header6-1u" data-rv-view="390" style="overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="mbr-overlay">
                        <video class="header6 cid-qshCJQFC7b" autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                            <source src="vid/bridgebg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container" style="background: rgba(97, 134, 165,0.7); width: 100%;">
                        <div class="media-container-column mbr-white col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                            <h2 class="mbr-section-title align-center text-white">OUR CORPORATE DONORS</h2>
                            <p class="mbr-text align-center pb-3 mbr-fonts-style" style="font-size: 14px;    letter-spacing: 0.7px; font-weight: lighter;"><!--display-5-->These Buy-it-Forward Companies <br class="hide-in-web"> Deserve your Support&nbsp;
                                <br>
                            </p>
                            <div class="mbr-section-btn align-center">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 logo-civicom text-right">
                                        <a class="display-4" style="margin-right: 20px;" target="_blank" href="" alt="" style="margin-top: 25px;"></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 logo-teamspan text-left">
                                        <a class="display-4" target="_blank" href="" alt="" style="margin-top: 25px;"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

Now if I use this code:

```html
<video style="margin-top: -200px;" class="header6 cid-qshCJQFC7b" autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                            <source src="vid/bridgebg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
```

As you can see I used `margin-top` to manually adjust the background, I would get what I want but it would mess up the mobile version and will look like this:

[Messed up mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9uJB.png)

Is there anyway I could adjust this background without messing up the mobile version? Like an auto syntax or something?

Comment: Please edit your snippet so as to make them work. As of now, the video they are linking to are not available, and the CSS is not included. Don't forget to click on `run` in the snippet editing window to make sure that what you post on StackOverflow is what you observe on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the problem as I am unable to see the video. But here is an attempt. First of all, I would not recommend Inline style. It is not the most sustainable way of writing stylesheets. I would recommend adding the style in your external CSS.  Also, I would recommend using percentages instead of pixel values. The best way to solve this problem according to me is to use [media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). 
A media query is used to arrange and manipulate elements in a browser on different screen sizes so you can do something like this.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header6{
    margin-top: -20%;
  }
}    
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .header6 {
       margin-top: -20%;
     }
 }
@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .header6{
        margin-top: -10%
    }
}
```

Keep tweaking the margins until you find the sweet spot.
Hope this helps! Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good reference about customizing CSS properties depending on screen size. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp